# Components mounting many times

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm simply trying to toggle the visibility of a React component on a specific keypress.

This is working perfectly, but it seems every Time i toggle the component visibility using ctrl+`, the process gets slower and slower, and my console.log(e) from the onKey function in my app component gets called 10,50,100, 1000 times etc.

This is what I have so far

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>

  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

function App() {
  const [compHidden, toggleComp] = useState(true);

  const onKey = (e) => {
    console.log(e)
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.key === '`') {
      toggleComp(!compHidden);
    }
  }

  document.addEventListener('keydown', onKey);

  return (
      <ComponentToHide hidden={compHidden}/>
  );
}

function ComponentToHide(props) {

  return (
    <div style={{display: props.hidden ? 'none' : 'flex'}}>
     <p>Visible</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Do not use `document.addEventListener` inside the render function, as that function is called every time your component renders and it will add a new event listner each time.

Instead, use the [React Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) [`React.useEffect()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) to add the event listner only once as the component is mounted:

```js
function App() {
  const [compHidden, setCompHidden] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const onKey = (e) => {
      console.log(e)
      if(e.ctrlKey && e.key === '`') {
        setCompHidden(value => !value);
      }
    }

    document.addEventListener('keydown', onKey);

    return () => document.removeEventListener('keydown', onKey);
  }, [])

  return (
      <ComponentToHide hidden={compHidden}/>
  );
}
```

Two things to note:

1. useEffect's second argument, just an empty array, tells React only to run that function once at the beginning of the components lifecycle
2. You can return a cleanup function that is ran as your component is unmounted. We use this here to remove the event listener to fix an additional memory leak.

Comment: This seems to work perfectly toggling it to visible the first time, but then stops working after that (can't hide it)

Would it have something to do with this warning?

React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: compHidden'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. You can also do a functional update 'toggleComp(c => ...)' if you only need 'compHidden' in the 'toggleComp' call  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Comment: Ahhhh, I believe the setState function should be updated to use the callback form to modify its value. I've updated the code in the post